# Django ORM Join statement

Tags: mysql, django

I have a problem with joining the data from two tables together.

My model looks like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    kod_baka = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class)
    rfid = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class User_account_student(models.Model):
    kod_baka = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, editable=False)
    default_passwd = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

What I need to do, is to select data from these two tables together, linked by the column `kod_baka`. The SQL query would look like

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
INNER JOIN User_account_student ON
    Student.kod_baka = User_account_student.kod_baka`
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You also need to improve your model. Is there any reason you are not using Foreignkeys between `Student` and `User_account_student`? It will make it a lot easier...

Comment: Yeah, there was a reason I decided to make it like this, but I cannot remember it any more, it was a long time ago. Anyway, all I need is to write the query provided in Django ORM

Comment: I solved it well enough by using the `objects.raw()` query, but my question still persists: is it possible to do that via the ORM itself?

Comment: Yes, by defining `kod_baka` as a ForeignKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    kod_baka = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class)
    rfid = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class User_account_student(models.Model):
    kod_baka = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, editable=False)
    default_passwd = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Membership(models.model):
    student=models.ForeignKey(Student)
    user_account_student=models.ForeignKey(User_account_student)


s = Student.objects.get(....).kod_baka
User_account_student.objects.filter(membership__student.kod_baka = s).distinct()
```